# Redux Options Framework - Slides search

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

Im currently using Redux plugin for WordPress with the slides "field": https://docsv3.redux.io/core/fields/slides/index.html .

The problem is i have 55+ slides.

I can get slide with index "0" this way:

```
if (isset($redux_demo['opt-slides']) && !empty($redux_demo['opt-slides'])) {
    echo 'Slide 1 Title: '         . $redux_demo['opt-slides'][0]['title'];
    echo 'Slide 1 URL: '           . $redux_demo['opt-slides'][0]['url'];
}
```

However i need to quickly get the slide with a specific title, like "homepage", the way im currently doing this is using PHP array_search() and go through every single slide in **$redux_demo['opt-slides']** before it finds the one with the given name.

Isn't there a more optimized (performance wise) solution to this problem?, similar to:

```
$redux_demo['opt-slides']["homepage"]['url']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the next code, a little function that needs 2 params your slides array The search term in Title (exact title, by now but you could change this behaviour with something not naive like a regex expression. Finally return the index of your slide.

```
$redux_demo =
    [
        0 => [
            'title' => 'Mi title',
            'url' => 'https//....'
        ],
        1 => [
            'title' => 'Mi title2',
            'url' => 'https//....'
        ]

    ];

//So you can 

function search_redux($redux_demo,$search){
  if (isset($redux_demo) && !empty($redux_demo)) {

    foreach($redux_demo as $index=>$slide){
      
      if($slide['title']===$search){
        return $index;
      } 
    }
 
  }
   
   

};

$result=search_redux($redux_demo,'Mi title2');
```

Comment: That works but is still ressource expensive, as it have to loop through every item.

Comment: That will return your index when find it. An stop the loop. That code is totally inexpensive, WordPress has many many others stucks points, from querys to other loops inside loops.